# pythonic way to manipulate nested dict from dotted path?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary, an encryption function and a dotted path, I want to apply my encryption function to encrypt specific field.
Example:

mydict

```
{"a":{
     ...
     "b":{
          ...
          "c":"value"
           }
      }
 }
```

field path: `a.b.c`

I want to execute encryption function on `c` value and modify my dict.
What's the most efficent and pythonic way?

Comment: you mean the whole dictionary is given to you as string and it includes a 'dotted path'? what's a dotted path?

Comment: yes, i have a dict and a dotted path, by 'dotted path' i mean if 'a.b.c' is provided encrypt d['a']['b']['c'], if 'x.y.z.k' instead encrypt d['x']['y']['z']['k'] and so on

Comment: you probably want to edit the question and clarify or it may get downvoted

Comment: well, this may help https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you mean is have the number of nestings be variable according to a string like `'a.b.c'`:

```
d = {"a":{"b":{"c":"value"}}}
dotted = 'a.b.c'

paths, current = dotted.split('.'), d
for p in paths[:-1]:
    current = current[p]
current[paths[-1]] = encrypt(current[paths[-1]])
```

this will modify the given dictionary `d` to be

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":"whatever the encrypted value is"}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below function

```
def update(d, path, value):
    out = path.split('.', 1)
    key = out[0]
    if len(out) > 1:
        path = out[1]
        return update(d[key], path, value)
    else:
        d[key] = value
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'value'}}}
path = 'a.b.c'
value = 100 # let's consider encrypted value
update(d, path, value)
print(d )
# Output: {'a': {'b': {'c': 100}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little too late and **tricky** but to be **functional**:

```py
from functools import reduce

d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'value'}}}
path = 'a.b.c'

# result will be 'value'
result = reduce(dict.__getitem__, path.split('.'), d)
```

Answer (score 1):

By recommended practices you should probably get it by,

```
d['a']['b']['c']
```

Or you may add a Class to objectify for using dot (A hacky solution though).

```
class Objectify(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                self.__dict__.update(key=Objectify(obj[key]))
            else:
                self.__dict__.update(key=obj[key])

d = Objectify({'a': {'b': {'c': True}}})
print(d.a.b.c)
```

Result:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary are quite efficient in python, so you can directly encrypt it:

```
# d -- dictionary
key1 = d.keys()[0]
key2 = d[key1].keys()[0]
key3 = d[key1][key2].keys()[0]
d[key1][key2][key3] = encrypt(d[key1][key2][key3])
```

Comment: how to make it automatically? whatever the dotted path is?

Comment: What do you mean by dotted path?

Comment: if 'a.b.c' is provided encrypt d['a']['b']['c'], if 'x.y.z.k' instead encrypt d['x']['y']['z']['k'] and so on

Comment: Ahh I see. Well, you need to differentiate somehow keys. So it depends on your task. For example, if you know that there is a single key in each nested disctionary, you can easily access it. Is it the case with your nested dictionary?

Comment: yes exactly, i would like to acces as you said, but dinamically

Comment: but how should i take the path from the dotted path i mentioned before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glom assignment](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutation.html#assignment) to get and modify the value in-place:

```
from glom import glom, assign, Assign, Spec

d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'value'}}}
```

Option 1 with [regular glom assignment](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutation.html#glom.Assign:%7E:text=Assign%20is%20to-,deep%2Dapply,-a%20function%3A):

```
value_to_encrypt = glom(d,'a.b.c') # deep-get
_ = assign(d, 'a.b.c', encrypt(value_to_encrypt)) # deep-modify 'c' in place
```

Option 2 with [deep-apply](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutation.html#glom.Assign:%7E:text=Assign%20is%20to-,deep%2Dapply,-a%20function%3A):

```
_ = glom(d, Assign('a.b.c', Spec(('a.b.c', encrypt)))) # applies 'encrypt' on a.b.c and modifies the value in place
```